# make new Finder windows open at current folder

Tags: macos, finder

In Windows when I browse in Explorer, if I open a new Explorer window, it is opened to the same location as the window I had selected when I hit Ctrl-N. Is there a way of doing the same with Finder? So if I'm browsed to Pictures, when I hit Command-N, the new Finder window opens showing Pictures.

**Edit:** to clarify, what happens now is that regardless of where I have browsed to, when I hit Command-N, the new Finder window opens in my home directory `/Users/my_user/`.

Comment: OK. I am a dummy. I read your question 3 times, and still don't get it. You want to open a new window of same folder as window before (a duplicate). I use cmd-o....

Comment: Yeah, it's convenient when you're moving files. Say I've got some files in Folder1/Folder2 that I want to move to Folder1/Folder3. In Windows, I would open Folder1 in Explorer, hit Ctrl-N and the second window would also be open to Folder1. Then I browse to Folder2 in one window and Folder3 in the other. I don't have to first navigate to Folder1 in the second window because it's already open to there.

Comment: Sarah - your use case is very common. Apple's recent folders design doesn't really help, so most people just put the common locations in the sidebar or use a launch tool like [Launchbar](http://obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) to push files to a specific folder with the keyboard rather than having Finder keep track of the last location. The big problem is the concept that Finder maintains a "current" folder once you close the last remaining finder window.

Answer (score 10):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        target of Finder window 1
        make new Finder window to result
    on error
        make new Finder window to home
    end try
end tell
```

This would also change some properties:

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        tell Finder window 1
            set t to target
            set b to bounds
            set cv to current view
            set sw to sidebar width
            set sv to statusbar visible
            set tv to toolbar visible
        end tell
    on error
        make new Finder window to home
        return
    end try
    make new Finder window to t
    tell result
        set bounds to {(item 1 of b) + 20, (item 2 of b) + 20, (item 3 of b) + 20, (item 4 of b) + 20}
        set current view to cv
        set sidebar width to sw
        set statusbar visible to sv
        set toolbar visible to tv
    end tell
end tell
```

`target of Finder window 1` is the folder shown on the title bar. It doesn't depend on the selection in list view.

You can also use ⌃⌘↑ to reveal the location shown on the title bar in a new window. It doesn't work in column view if the toolbar is hidden though.

Comment: +1. Nice script + info! One question, how would make the fallback window your _default_ selected New Finder window option if you've changed it from 'home'?

Comment: You could use `defaults read com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath || defaults read com.apple.finder NewWindowTarget`. NewWindowTargetPath doesn't exist if the default location is for example the computer view.

Answer (score 9):

Enable show path in the view menu (not sure about the menu names but it should appear at the bottom of the finder window) then cmd + double click the folder you want to open, in this case, the last folder is your current folder.

I made an image but can't post it :\

Edit: Image example [image: Duplicate Finder window]

Comment: Thanks @grgarside, I was following your suggestion and appears I now can add images.

Comment: new tab, not new window

Answer (score 6):

Pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> will open a new Finder tab/window at the same location.

For opening it in a tab, you must have enabled "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows" in Preferences/General. If you want to open it in a complete different window, just leave it disabled.

[image: Open folders in tabs...]

Comment: This is the best / easiest solution I've found - thank you for this! Never knew this shortcut. It's preferable to Command-double click. Only problem is you have to have the folder selected in the Finder - if you have selected anything within the folder, the shortcut does nothing. : (

Answer (score 2):

It is simple:

Go to "finder > preferences > general tab"

Uncheck to "Open folders in tabs instead of new window".

You're done!

⌘+double-click to the folder.

Comment: But that doesn't open the folder you're currently viewing in a new tab, it opens the one you clicked.

Comment: couldn't get you.

Comment: Isn't this what OP wanted? `make new Finder windows open at current folder`

Comment: They way I read it, they want a way to open a duplicate of the current Finder window... but perhaps I misunderstood.

Comment: That what it does.

Comment: Hmm ok, it doesn't for me. That's odd.

Comment: Well, it does NOT open the "current folder" but the one you've got selected/clicked. Now, the point is that can actually click on the current folder provided that you've enabled the flag to show the current path at the bottom of each finder window and such is wide enough to show the last folder.

Answer (score 0):

Finder on OS X doesn't have an option to re-open the most recent folder.

It is tracked in the Go menu, but if you look at the Finder preferences, it expects you to leave the default new window folder or select another target which will be the folder shown each time you open a new window.

Comment: is it cmd-o he is asking about?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I doubt it. The Open menu item in finder doesn't open a new window (command-O by default). Only the new windows commands actually open a new finder window.

Comment: Actually, at least on 10.8.3, Command-O opens a new Finder window. As does Command-N, so what the heck is up with that?

Comment: @Zo219 Interesting. I have 4 Macs and **File > Open** is disabled in finder unless you have selected a file or folder. I wonder what is selected or different on Macs where Open does something when nothing is selected. Even if I turn on the setting "Always Open Folders in New Window", I still get no Open menu enabled in Finder when nothing is selected. If this works for you, it's unclear why several Macs that are set up brand new with no changes on 10.8.3 don't work the same.

Comment: Damn, you're right. And all these years and I never twigged on Select anything and hit Open. For above comment, I always had a Folder selected. Not sure anymore about answer below, either. Comm-N and Comm-O seem to do same thing.

Answer (score 0):

⌃⌘↑ and ⌃⌘O / ⌃⌘↓ invert the behavior for opening new windows for folders in some cases:

- If "Always open folders in a new window" is not checked: all views when the toolbar is shown, all views except column view when the toolbar is not shown.
- If "Always open folders in a new window" is checked: no views when the toolbar is shown, all views when the toolbar is not shown.

So if "Always open folders in a new window" is not checked and the toolbar is not hidden, you can use ⌃⌘↑ to open an enclosing folder in a new window or ⌃⌘O / ⌃⌘↓ to open a selected folder in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens now is that regardless of where I have browsed to, when I
>   hit Command-N, the new Finder window opens in my home directory
>   /Users/my_user/

When there are no Finder windows open, a new Finder window created by clicking on Finder in the dock, from the Finder menu, or by using Command-N, will open to the folder you have set in Finder preferences.

BUT if Finder preferences are set to Always Open Folders in New Window, Command-O will open a new window for any selected folder.

(Seems to me there used to be a shortcut to close the previous window as you opened the new.)

Answer (score 0):

[Finder open new Finder tab in the same directory](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117754/finder-open-new-finder-tab-in-the-same-directory)

"It still works in Monterey for opening a selected folder, so pressing Command + Up arrow and then Command + Ctrl + O will give you a new tab like the one you had, but you will need to press Command + Down arrow in the original tab to get it back to where you were. –
Nagel
"