# Finder open new Finder tab in the same directory

Tags: finder, macos

Is it possible to configure finder in Mavericks to open new tab (by clicking plus sign or cmd+t) in the same directory by default?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Control ^</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> in Finder without having anything selected (otherwise you will open-tab to the selection if it's a folder instead).

Pressing simultaneously <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Control ^</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> will open **a new tab** in the **same folder** as the **currently** opened folder.

No need for any extra things in OS X for this ;-)

Comment: How the hell do you  not select somthing i listview.

Comment: Ok, possible with command mouseclick, but possible with keyboard? So i can set up a karabiner thing  for this?

Comment: Make sure that you dont have anything selected in the current tab, just click some empty space.

Comment: Nice! To make sure nothing is selected, perform shortcut `Command + Option + A`. Then `Command + Ctrl + O`. Using this combination in BetterTouchTool, working well!

Comment: Not working anymore in MONETERY

Comment: Confirming what @Khanakia said, this used to work, but in Monterey it doesn't, sadly

Comment: It still works in Monterey for opening a selected folder, so pressing `Command + Up arrow` and then `Command + Ctrl + O` will give you a new tab like the one you had, but you will need to press `Command + Down arrow` in the original tab to get it back to where you were.

Answer (score 26):

There is another way to accomplish opening a new tab in the same location, if you don't absolutely need to have it as standard.

Open a Finder window and make sure that the Path bar is shown either by going to View -> Show Path Bar or by pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. You then get the folder hierarchy in a bar at the bottom of the window. Just hold  <kbd>⌘</kbd> and double click any item in that bar to open that folder in a new tab (or new window if not using tabs).

[image]

Comment: Nice ! I knew there should've been something with the path bar! How do you disable tabs so that you get a new window?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă Open Finder preferences, go to the General (leftmost) tab and uncheck "Open folders in tabs instead of new windows"

Answer (score 8):

Another similar approach to the one described by Lizzan but which doesn't need the path bar to be visible is to Cmd-click on the current folder in the title bar of your Finder window. This drops down a list of the hierarchical path to the current folder - so the 2nd entry in the list (after the current folder itself) is the parent of the current folder. If you cmd-click on the parent folder it will open in a new tab. To minimise the clicks required if you cmd-click and hold the cmd-click down then when you release it on the parent folder it will open in a new tab.

This approach is very useful if the folder you want in the new tab is actually a sibling of the current folder in the path hierarchy.

Answer (score 5):

In Monterey and later versions of MacOS:

press the Command key while you double-click the folder.
The folder opens in a new tab or window, depending on your Finder preferences.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to create a automator action and turn it to a service, which you can assign a keyboard shortcut too.

Open automator > select create new service > where it says "service receives selected" choose [files or folder] > where it says "in" choose [Finder.app]

Then find the automator action "reveal finder items" and drag it in. That's it. Save it as a service and then go to keyboard prefs and assign it something like ⌃⌘O. Now when you have a folder selected in finder and do that shortcut it will open a new tap to that location.

It's not perfect. I think I like the Command click title and then command click folder technique better but I thought I'd put it out there.

[image: automator setup]

Please write to apple in their feedback page requesting an official finder preference for "new Finder tabs show:" [last opened directory] or [current directory] Maybe they will include in 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no option to do this. The new tab uses the following setting from Finder preferences. There's no option to use the current location or a different location for tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a Finder add-on/replacement called [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com), which has (among other finder tweaks) an option to open new tabs with the location of the last active tab/window.

It's commercial software ($18USD at the time of writing) so probably only worth it if you also want its other features & tweaks.

Comment: Totalfinder is buggy. Also can not see this functionality requested is in it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to complex modifications in **Karabiner**.

Basically it will simulate go up once, go down once, then cmd + ctrl + o. The first two to make sure nothing is selected.

It is a bit slow though because we have to wait until we believe the new window / tab is done opening.

```
    {
        "conditions": [
            {
                "bundle_identifiers": [
                    "^com.apple.finder"
                ],
                "type": "frontmost_application_if"
            }
        ],
        "from": {
            "key_code": "t",
            "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                    "left_command"
                ]
            }
        },
        "to": [
            {
                "key_code": "up_arrow",
                "modifiers": [
                    "right_command",
                    "right_control"
                ]
            }
        ],
        
        "parameters": {
            "basic.to_delayed_action_delay_milliseconds": 500 // 300 is fine for desktop, but laptop balls out on 300. Too slow.  
        },
        
        "to_delayed_action": {
            "to_if_invoked": [
                {
                    // We default to the command 2 list view because otherwise it will break 
                    "key_code": "2",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "right_command"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "key_code": "o",
                    "modifiers": [
                        "right_command"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "type": "basic"
    }
```

Comment: Just found another way to deselect: perform shortcut `Command + Option + A`. Then `Command + Ctrl + O`. Using this in `BetterTouchTool`, working well!

Comment: Deselect all, awesome! I will update my code!

Comment: Command + Option + A no longer works in Monterey. Will deselect all. And not open anything after. left_command + left_control + o has different behaviour now. It will open something in a new tab, but only if the mouse is on a directory. So now, i open in new tab then go up to go to the parent directory. However, if a file is selected this won't work right now.

Comment: Difficult to get working in monterey actually.

Comment: Added the fix for monterey.

Comment: Uh! Drastic edit.

Answer (score 0):

In Monterey the Finder window pull-down menu (circle with 3 dots) has an "Open in New Tab" command. I assigned that a keyboard shortcut, ^⌥⌘T, problem solved!

Comment: That menu option seems to open a selected folder in the current folder, not the current folder itself as asked in the question.

Comment: Right, if you select a folder. But when you open a folder nothing's selected, and if you've selected a folder just click somewhere else in the window to unselect it. This works in both list and icon views, those are the only 2 I use.

Comment: Thx. I have Monterey v12.5.1 installed on my Mac but I don't see an "Open in New Tab" option in the drop-down menu that appears when I click on the "circle with 3 dots" icon at the top right of a Finder window, even when no file or folder is selected. I see an "Open in New Window" option in that drop-down menu when only a folder is selected. Does one need to make any setting changes in somewhere in System Preferences for such an option to appear?

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Ventura 13.1.  If you use this while no folder is selected, nothing happens.  It does open in new tab when a folder is selected.

Comment: What is the shortcut for if i have to mouse click in some cases? Apple should get their shit together.